# How to make bootstrap 3 unresponsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a website with bootstrap 3, so by default it's responsive. However, I don't want it to be responsive (it's long story).

Basically I just want it so that on tablets and phones you have to zoom in and out to read it. It's just a basic brochure website which is why responsiveness isn't necessary.

I've tried taking out the meta view-port tags and googled how to do it endless times but I can't make it to act/look like a normal website, if that makes sense. What do I need to do to make Bootstrap 3 unresponsive?

Comment: Note that, in addition to those instructions, for zooming, you may need to set the [meta viewport tag](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/) to a specific value - or just plainly remove it as zooming tends to be the default. (Though I guess OP mentions already fiddling with that. Some code would be nice to help there...)

Answer (score 0):

```
  .Container{width: 960px;} // add your designed width
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .Container{width: 960px;}// add your designed width
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .Container{width: 960px;}// add your designed width
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .Container{width: 960px;}// add your designed width
}
```

Write it your external CSS file. Remember First add bootstrap.css then add your external.css.